# Querying database using entity framework in Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Suppose i have a query like

```
var tableList = dbcontext.tbl_name.findAll().tolist();
```

which returns a list having some 200 rows.
Then i am querying the required from the list "tableList" such as

```
var top5 = tableList.(to find top 5 records in sorted according to some column).tolist()
bool trueVal = tableLilst.(some column having value 1)
var name = tableList.(some column with name "example")
```

etc.. like some 7 queries which is in all in a single method and i need all this seperately not as a single query.

So is it better to do like above or

```
var top5= dbcontext.tbl_name.top5 query.
var trueVal = dbcontext.tbl_name.true value query
var name = dbcontext.tbl_name.name query
```

Please suggest

Comment: please check [this link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)  and find IQueryable vs. IEnumerable text where you get how to get data properly from db in single hit.

Answer (score 0):

if you write 7 query to load data from server it will fire query 7 times to server

because you use iquerable which will rum on database server

so you have to fire query one on db server ger ienumarable data and then apply 7 filter to it to get data

Comment: What if the number of records in table in something greater like more than 10000 or something???

Comment: first i will recommend you  to use Stored procedure  for this type of data operation which will return all your 7 value .....or use linq that will return row all 7 values in list using internal queries  as iquerable so that all filter run once on server